# onKeydown not responding on third try

Tags: android

I'm adding a onKeyDown on almost every layout of my app, cuz i'm adding a custom menú, and i want to call it using the menu key, but i found something funny

In the constructor for my options layout i set `setFocusable(true)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` so the actions on `onKeyDown` are launched, and when i'm showing the layout, i have this function `updateDisplay(View v)` on to which i pass my layout and show it with `setContentView`.

I do this mostly to have the back key return to the previous view. So, it works once, works twice, but the third time i show the form, and press the back key, it wont enter the `onKeyDown`method, it exits the program. Any idea???? I'm totally lost here

Comment: Have you tried running your app in a debugger? Do you get any error messages in the log when the program exits?

Comment: no, no error is thrown, it just, doesn't reenter the onKeyDown, and now its happening when i enter for a second time to the options form

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to make an options menu in android is to override the [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) method in your `Activity`. This will probably work better than implementing `onKeyDown` for every layout.

Comment: the thing is, each layout has different options on the menu, and i dont want to clog the activity class, i'd like to keep it in each layout class, so each layout class will be implementing its own onKeyDown method